# sklearn loocv.split returning a smaller test and train array than expected

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation

As I have a small dataset I'm using `LOOCV`(leave one out cross validation) in `sklearn`.

When I ran my classifier I received the following error:

`"Number of labels=41 does not match number of samples=42"`.

I generated the test and training sets using the following code:

```
otu_trans = test_train.transpose()
# transpose otu table 
merged = pd.concat([otu_trans, metadata[status]], axis=1, join='inner')
# merge phenotype column from metadata file with transposed otu table

X = merged.drop([status],axis=1)

# drop status from X 
y = merged[status]


encoder = LabelEncoder()
y = pd.Series(encoder.fit_transform(y),
index=y.index, name=y.name)
# convert T and TF lables to 0 and 1 respectively

loocv = LeaveOneOut()
loocv.get_n_splits(X)

for train_index, test_index in loocv.split(X):
    print("TRAIN:", train_index, "TEST:", test_index)
    X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]
    print(X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test)
```

[input data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/842gbpr3m4mkoql/input.csv?dl=0)

When I check the shape of `X_train` and `X_test` it is `42,41` rather than `41,257` as I believe it should be, thus it appears the data is being partitioned along the wrong axis.

Can anyone explain to me why this is happening?

Thank you

Comment: Can you show some more details?

Comment: @adamsorbie in X how many samples and variables do you have ? what is the shape of the initial X matrix ? same questions for y matrix

Comment: So there are 42 samples and 257 features i.e. X.shape returns (42,257) and y.shape returns (42,) initially. In this case, after splitting X.shape should be (41,257) right?

Comment: @adamsorbie also, if you need more help, post the full code and data if it is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the initial matrix `X` will be not affected at all.
It is only used to produce indices and split the data.

The shape of the initial `X` will be always the same.

Now, here is a **simple example** using `LOOCV` spliting:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import LeaveOneOut

# I produce fake data with same dimensions as yours.
#fake data
X = np.random.rand(41,257)
#fake labels
y = np.random.rand(41)

#Now check that the shapes are correct:
X.shape
y.shape
```

This will give you:

```
(41, 257)
(41,)
```

Now the **splitting**:

```
loocv = LeaveOneOut()
loocv.get_n_splits(X)

for train_index, test_index in loocv.split(X):
    print("TRAIN:", train_index, "TEST:", test_index)
    X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]

    #classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
    #classifier.predict(X_test)


X_train.shape
X_test.shape
```

This prints:

```
(40, 257)
(1, 257)
```

As you can see, the `X_train` contains `40` samples and the `X_test` contains only `1` sample. This is correct since we use `LOOCV` splitting.

**The initial X matrix had 42 samples in total so we use 41 for training and 1 for testing.**

This loop will produce a lot of `X_train` and `X_test` matrices. To be specific, it will produce `N` matrices where `N` = `number of samples` (in our case: `N = 41`).

`N` is equal to the `loocv.get_n_splits(X)`.

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks! Unfortunately though when I run X_train.shape I still get (42, 41) rather than (40,257). Before running this I transposed my data is it possible that this is causing this problem?

Comment: of course !! this is the problem !! do not transpose. the X matrix should be [number of samples, number of variables/features]

Comment: Ah I see, simple solution then. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Could I ask why this is the case with LOOCV? I thought it was standard in ML to have features as rows and the samples as columns? The data here is a subset of a larger dataset and when using cross-validation with this I have to transpose.

Comment: In sklearn library the X is [samples, features]. You can know in advance what the shape of the matrix must be by looking at the documentation: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.LeaveOneOut.html Scroll down and you will see the following: X : array-like, shape (n_samples, n_features)

Comment: Ah okay, I see now. Thanks a lot!